# Python Selenium Multiple buttons with same class

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to launch into a platform with help of selenium chromedriver in python. 
But the platform offers Demo and real accounts which offers multiple click buttons with same class name. Please see the code below

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="username"> == $0
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="password"> == $0
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-launch" ng-transclude=""><button class="platform-btn ng-scope">Launch platform</button></button>
<button class="platform-btn ng-scope">Launch Platform</button>


<input type="hidden" name="username" value="username_demo"> == $0
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="password"> == $0
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-launch" ng-transclude=""><button class="platform-btn ng-scope">Launch platform</button></button>
<button class="platform-btn ng-scope">Launch Platform</button>
```

**Xpath code**

Real

```
/html/body/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div/ui-view/section/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/tc-platform-launch/form/button/button
```

Demo

```
/html/body/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div/ui-view/section/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[8]/tc-platform-launch/form/button/button
```

How can I launch demo and real account in selenium python???

Comment: do you want these links to open in two new tabs?

Comment: Yes, It will automatically open new tab when you click on the button

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: It's giving error :

Comment: demo=browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div/ui-view/section/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[8]/tc-platform-launch/form/button/button")

Comment: is variable demo None?

Comment: demo=browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div/ui-view/section/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[8]/tc-platform-launch/form/button/button")

demo.click()
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])

Comment: I added what you suggest

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: it's working. I added (browser.window_handles[0] @thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly find element by xpath .This would work if on clicking button opens a new tab

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
real=browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div/ui-view/section/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/tc-platform-launch/form/button/button")
demo=browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div/ui-view/section/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[8]/tc-platform-launch/form/button/button")
real.click()
demo.click()
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])#To work on demo
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-2])#to Work on real
```

Comment: could you share the link of website?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't because it's tied with my account details. I successfully login to account by sending username and passwords keys on main page directly but now I need to launch the cloud platforms by selecting demo or real manually. I hope you get the idea